# Why isn't Angular rendering my css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have an issue with [angular2-seed app](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed) where it can't seem to render my `css` when i put it in `index.html` 
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base href="<%= APP_BASE %>">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title><%= APP_TITLE %></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- inject:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/material.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <!-- endinject -->
</head>
<body>

<div class="mdl-badge">Hello</div>
<sd-app>
  <div class="mdl-spinner"></div>
</sd-app>
```

Im pointing to the correct path to the `css` file but when i use any class, it just doesn't render at all 
I tried `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../node_modules/material-design-lite/material.css">` which shouldn't make any difference, but got the same result
**Edit**

Here's how my project looks like, I've moved the `css` and `js` to the `src`, hope its clearer now [image]

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: check the network tab in the dev tools  , it might gives an error on it

Comment: Yeah I've also done that, noticed that my css file is not being loaded, but what i can't understand is why?

Comment: Did you check angualr working properly with a browser debugger? Sometimes, I exprience that css isn't loaded if angular generating error

Comment: What error are you getting in the network tab now that you have moved the file into the project folder? Also can you access material.css by entering its supposed URL into the browser address bar?

Comment: What a silly thing to do >.< i've put my css inside the ` <!-- inject:css -->   <!-- endinject -->` while i am not using gulp. Moved my css reference outside the inject and it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Angular. The path to your `css/material.css` must be incorrect.

You need to have a `/css` directory in the same directory you're hosting your web server from. So if your project is in `/myproject` you need to have a `/myproject/css` folder.

The path MUST be relative to your root folder. If it isn't, then `css/material.css` will not work, because without a `/` forward slash at the beginning, the root is *relative* to the current folder.

As was mentioned in the comments, you can enter the exact path into your address bar in the browser to see if that css file will load. If it doesn't, you've got a path issue. This can most likely be resolved by appending `../` to travel down a directory, or appending `/` to make the path absolute to the root of the web server.

Comment: I know that, and as i stated, I'm pointing to the correct path to my css file

Comment: @BishoAdam: but is that path inside your webhosted folder? The relative path ../../node_modules/... could easily be outside. An easy way to check is to enter the path to the css into the address bar and see if it will fetch it.